# Opening Python program from Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have opened Anaconda - then i maneuvered to the directory where a certain python program i want to run actually lies.

I then tried the %run  command.

But the command does not seem to work!

So how am i to run that program?

Does anyone know the right command that one has to use in the black colored Anaconda console command line, to run a Python program existing in a certain directory (to which the command line has been taken to)

Comment: `python path_to_program.py` from the Anaconda dir. Does it work?

Comment: By "Anaconda" do you mean IPython/IPython Notebook?

Comment: I guess he meant Anaconda console

Answer (score 0):

`%run` is a command that's run from inside of IPython. To use it, you should start `ipython` first. Or just run `python program.py` (if your program is named `program.py`).